# Angular save http.data to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to save my data comming from a $http request to an array. So I haven't call the api each time I need this list.

For now I have a service looking like this:

```
angular.module('schwimmfestivalApp')
  .service('httpService', function($http) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var articleList = [];
    var food = [];


    this.getArticles = function() {
      if (articleList < 1) {
        $http.get('https://www.anmeldung.schwimmfestival.de/server/func/getArtikel.php').then(response => {
          articleList = response.data;
          console.log(articleList);
        });
      }
      return articleList;
    };

    this.getArticleByCategory = function(category) {
      if (food.length < 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.getArticles().length; i++) {
          if (this.getArticles()[i].kategorie == category) {
            food.push(this.getArticles()[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      return food;
    };

    this.getFood = function() {
      console.log('Food: '+ food);
      return this.getArticleByCategory('TN Essen')
    };
  });
```

I read something about async calls and so my code will go on before the array is filled.
Can you help me how to build this service so I can work with this array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not an Angular issue. Everything in Javascript is asynchronous: ajax, keyboard, mouse, etc. You have to write your code using callbacks/event-handlers. You should probably play around with setTimeout() to see how it all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you try to return a synchronous result with an asynchronous operation.

See this code :

```
this.getArticles = function() {
    if (articleList < 1) {
        $http.get(url).then(response => {
            articleList = response.data;
        });
    }
    return articleList;
};
```

When your function is evaluated, you first call an http URL and return an empty array. Then, your http service respond (maybe few secondes later) and you set `response.data` to `articleList`. When you do this, the previous empty array you returned before is lost, so the caller will **always** get the empty array.

What you want to do is handled by `ngResource` module, but you can simulate this behavior :

```
this.getArticles = function() {
    if (articleList < 1) {
        $http.get(url).then(response => {
            articleList.push(...response.data);
        });
    }
    return articleList;
};
```

Note that the best way to solve your problem is probably to **return the promise** instead of using the hack below :

```
// Your service :
this.getArticles = function() {
    return $http.get(url).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    });
}

// Your controller :
myService.getArticles().then(response => {
    $scope.articles = response;
});
```

And if you do not want to call your http method each time, you can use the http cache available with angular :

```
// Your service :
this.getArticles = function() {
    return $http.get(url, { cache: true }).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: The cache: true option is what I was looking for.